# How to you pickle with evolving class objects

Tags: python, serialization, pickle, python-dataclasses

I'm making a python software that need to save complex (nested) dataclasses to disk. I've been using `pickle` which is working fine until I need to modify the class as i'm developing it. Then, I cannot load the pickle as I get an `AttributeError`. I understand that `pickle` requires the class to be the same, but it's difficult to work on a growing project when the pickled files con't be opened as soon as i improve the class. For instance, simply renaming attributes when refactoring, or cleaning up.

I'm sure this is a solved problem. Any clues? Is it possible to tell pickle to only load what it can and discard the rest leaving the new attributes go to default. Is there a better alternative (I tried `protobuf` and `msgpack` to no avail)

FYI: `json` is not an option, because part of the database are large `numpy` or `pandas`, or maybe later `xarray`, and even though these objects have serialisation methods, it still does not solve the problem that missing attributes will prevent `pickle.load`.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm sure this is a solved problem.

So, not "solved". Because there is not a single way to resolve that, as it is a too broad subject.

While Python has enough capabilities to allow one's classes to overcome this, there is no, and there could not be a default approach. What would unpickle do when reading state of an object with more fields that are in the data? Use default values? But where would it pick these defaults from? Dataclasses do provide defaults, but pickle can't know of those, unless there is an integration.

For code which stores its data in SQL, rather than using pickle, there are whole frameworks to handle migration alone - (see [Python's SQLAlchemy "Alembic"](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/), for example) - and, although automated, they can be tough to use, as the complexity of tracking changing models can be large.

> Any clues? Is it possible to tell
> pickle to only load what it can and discard the rest leaving the new
> attributes go to default. Is there a better alternative (I tried
> protobuf and msgpack to no avail)

So, you have a narrow  and well described objective, it may well be possible to do with the mechanisms provided by the language without looking at all corner cases that would be possible.

The approach will require that your classes have special-named methods describing how Pickle will handle them - thanks to Python multi-inheritance capabilities, those can be written in separated code, and you just inherit from it as a "mixin".

Bellow is a proof of concept.The bases for it are the docs at
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickling-class-instances

It turns out, all that is needed is to have a `__setstate__` defined for all your classes. Just add the class bellow as a base to your dataclasses and you should be good:

```
import warnings

class DefaultUnpicklerMixin:
    """Provides an unpickling method  which will restore
    dataclass instances, even if the model has gained new fields
    or dropped some fields since data was unpickled.
    """
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        try:
            current_fields = self.__class__.__dataclass_fields__
        except AttributeError:
            warnings.warn("DefaultUnpickler used in a class that is not a dataclass")
            current_fields = {}
        for key in list(state.keys()):
            if key not in current_fields:
                warnings.warn(f"Dropping unused field {key}")
                del state[key]
        # optionally add code to warn on new fields that are not 
        # on pickled data
        return self.__init__(**state)
```

If you want to have the data that is no longer a field in the class in an instance, simply replace the code inside `__getitem__` to do `self.__dict__.update(state)` , instead of calling `__init__`. (That won't set default values on the instance for the unknown fields, though)

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same problem. First I wrote a converter which saved my data to the new format but this lead to user errors on my side :).
Coming from an other background I thought something like overloading constructors.
Now when I load my data I always create a new dataclass object for a loaded object.
This might slow down your code and you have to update the methods but it works for me.
Some code snippets which might help you

```
@dataclass
class WizardCall():
   target: str

   def __init__(self, target,):
      self.target = target
      
   @classmethod
   def fromObject(cls, object):
      if hasattr(object, 'target'):
         localtarget = object.target
      else:
         localtarget = ""
      return cls(localtarget)

@dataclass
class NewTestStep():
    wizardList: list[WizardCall]

    def __init__(self, wizardList):
        self.wizardList = wizardList
 
   @classmethod
   def fromObject(cls, object):

      if hasattr(object, 'wizardList'):
         localwizardList: list[WizardCall]
         localwizardList = []
         for item in object.wizardList:
            temp: WizardCall
            temp = WizardCall.fromObject(item)
            localwizardList.append(temp)
      else:
         wizardList: list[WizardCall]
         wizardList = []
         localwizardList = wizardList

      return cls(localwizardList)

testResults = pickle.load(lzma.open(newLoadPath + "\\" + fileName, "rb" ))
  
for item in testResults:
     unpackedItem = item
     temp: NewTestData
     temp = NewTestData.fromObject(unpackedItem)
     convertedResults.append(temp)
```